# Упорядочить файлы по дате создания

Tags: php, массивы

подскажите, как правильно заменить значение ключа на метку времени создания файла для сортировки?

```
$entries = array();
        if ($handle = opendir(ROOT_DIR .ARTICLE_DIR)) {
            // получаем названия статей и названия файлов 
            while (false !==($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry !='.' and $entry != '..') {  

                    $entries[] = $entry;
                    foreach ($entries as $key => $entry){
                        заменить ключ на метку времени создания файла}

                    //usort($entries);
                    echo '<li><a href="index.php?show='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a></li>'.'<br>';

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: а если метки совпадать будут? может все же метка-значение, а ключ - имя?

Comment: Вроде бы не должны, файлы загружаются по одному на сервер

Comment: а смысл то всего этого какой? Если вы все равно просто выводите эту метку, дак зачем для этого переделывать массив? Если надо только вывести, дак получите и выведите, ключи массива то зачем тут? Сортировку по дате можно сделать и без ключей

Comment: Да, мне именно нужна сортировка по дате, но не приходит в голову как еще это можно сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам требуется отсортировать файлы по дате создания, то можно решить задачу в пару этапов. Сначала собрать массив с датами создания, используя `array_map` и  `filectime()`, затем слить оба массива и отсортировать по ключам (что в принципе вы и хотели).
Таким образом, если в `$entries`  у вас имена файлов, то как-то так:

```
$ct = array_map('filectime', $entries);
$data = array_combine($ct, $entries);
ksort($data);
```

В целом все же это несколько корявый подход, и лучше сначала собрать массив, где элемент будет содержать информацию о времени создания и имени файла. А затем уже воспользоваться обычной сортировкой. Это исключит вариант с потенциальным повторением ключей.

```
$entries = array_map(function($f){ 
                   return ['f' => $f, 'ct' => filectime($f)];
               }, $entries);

usort($entries, function($a, $b){ return $a['ct'] - $b['ct']; });

$entries = array_column($entries, 'f');
```

Можно, конечно, и просто воспользоваться использованием `filectime` в функции-компараторе

```
usort($entries, function($a, $b){ return filectime($a) <=> filectime($b);});
```

Но это повлечет больше обращений к файловой системе при сортировке.

---

*в дополнение:*

В первом случае, можно сделать ключами имена файлов, поменять местами аргументы `array_combine`, а затем использовав обычную сортировку `sort()` и вернув ключи `array_keys()` с именами. Пожалуй, это будет оптимальным вариантом.

```
$ct = array_map('filectime', $entries);
$data = array_combine($entries, $ct);
sort($data)
$files = array_keys($data);
```

---

**Еще более оптимальный вариант будет таким**

```
array_multisort(array_map('filectime', $entries), SORT_DESC, $entries);
```

Comment: Работает с @, выдает ошибку "Warning: filectime(): stat failed for"  думаю из за относительного пути, сможете подсказать как узнать в этом случае абсолютный ? (с помощью realpath)

Comment: @Nastya добавляйте в `$entries` не просто имена, а сразу целиком вместе с `ROOT_DIR .ARTICLE_DIR`